# Show under these conditions that $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f: ]a, b[ \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and let there be an $M > 0$ such that $|f'| \leq M$ on $]a, b[.$ Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $]a, b[.$

By differentiability, the function $f$ is continuous. However, I fail to see where the condition $|f'| = O(1)$ can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the mean-value theorem.  To that end, we have

$f(x)-f(x_0) = f'(\xi) (x-x_0)$ for some $a\le x_0<\xi <x\le b$.  Now, taking absolute values we find

$$\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(x_0)| &= |f'(\xi) (x-x_0)|\\
&=|f'(\xi)|\,|(x-x_0)|\\
&\le M\; |(x-x_0)|\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta = \epsilon/M$.

Comment: My pleasure!!  I enjoy helping.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to write! Sorry I erroneously deleted my previous comment.

Comment: You're more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use Mean value theorem.